# ng-change not firing when input type radio is selected

Tags: angular, radio-button

I have a grid

```
<div ng-app="test">
<div ng-controller="userModifyController as vm" ng-cloak>
<td width="5%" align="center">
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.SelectedRoleId" name="name" value="{{role.RoleId}}"
required="required" ng-change="vm.LoadStoreAttributesDetails()"/>
</td>
<div>
<div>
```

here the ng-change is fired only once when the page loads and the value is set up first time when the grid is bind with the existing selected value after which when i select any other option in the row the change event is not fired

when each radio button is clicked in a row it should fire the event in the angular controller file

```
vm.LoadStoreAttributesDetails = function () { alert("test"); }
```

Comment: Can you show you whole HTML ? I only see one input there

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the alias `vm.` it seems to work after doing that one change. Working example below!

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('angularTest', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', 'orderByFilter', function($scope, filterFilter, orderByFilter) {
  $scope.SelectedRoleId = '';
  $scope.role = {
    RoleId: 'test'
  };
  $scope.LoadStoreAttributesDetails = () =>  {
    console.log('asdf');
    alert("test");
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainContainer" ng-app="angularTest" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <td width="5%" align="center">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.SelectedRoleId" name="name" value="{{role.RoleId}}" required="required" ng-change="LoadStoreAttributesDetails()" />
  </td>
</div>
```